# Python: TypeError: 'int' object is unsubscriptable

Tags: python

I have written a program to calculate roots of a Weyl group.  However, I am getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./rootsAn.py", line 58, in <module>
    equals = isequal(x[0],y[0])
TypeError: 'int' object is unsubscriptable
```

I've looked up this error, but as far as I can tell, `x[0]` and `y[0]` are both arrays, not `ints`.  My code is:

```
def innerprod(a,b):
    x = 0
    y = 0
    while x < len(a):
        y += a[x]*b[x]
        x += 1
    return y

def isequal (a,b):
    x = len(a)- 1
    y = 0
    counter = 0
    while y < x:
        if a[y] == a[x]:
            counter+=1
        else:
            counter +=0
        y += 1
    if counter == x:
        return True
    else:
        return False


simplerootsht = []
simpleroots = []
positiverootsht=[]
positiveroots = []
dim = 3

n = 0
while n < dim-1:
        x = []
        s = 0
        while s < dim:
            if s == n:
                x.append(1)
            elif s == n + 1:
                x.append(-1)
            else:
                x.append(0)
            s += 1
        simplerootsht.append([x,1])
        simpleroots.append(x)
        n += 1
for c in simpleroots:
    positiveroots.append(c)
for d in simplerootsht:
    positiverootsht.append(d)

print positiverootsht

for x in positiverootsht:
    for y in simplerootsht:
        equals = isequal(x[0],y[0])
        if equals == True:
            pass
        print x[0], y[0]
        b = innerprod(x[0], y[0])
        a = len(x[0])
        if b == 0:
            pass
        else:
            r = x[1]
            q = r - b
            print r, q
            x = 1
            while x < q: 
                z = [sum(pair) for pair in zip(x[0], x*y[0])]
                if z not in positiveroots:
                    positiveroots.append(z)
                    positiverootsht.append([z,x[1] + y[1]])
                x += 1
```

Thanks!

Comment: `if condition: return True else: return False`. Hmmmm

Comment: This is really hard to read since you reuse the variable `x` is several completely different ways.. I'd suggest trying to be more descriptive, and also use more functions (so it's easier to track down where a variable came from).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example `x` iterates through the elements of `positiverootsht`.  `positiveroots` gets added to from `simpleroots` which has ints.  So `x` and `y`are both integers.

You are reusing the variables, so while `x` was an array earlier you turned it into an int with these lines:

```
for x in positiverootsht:
    for y in simplerootsht:
```

Comment: Thanks, I just realised all of the places where I called things the same.  Changing names to more descriptive things took care of the error!

Answer (score 3):

```
for x in positiverootsht:
```

positiverootsht is a list of integers.. they will give integer in x, when you iterate over them.. So, x is actually an int..They can't be subscripted like x[0] in `isequal()` method..

And so is `y`.. It is also an `int` type.

**So,below line won't work: -**

```
equals = isequal(x[0],y[0])
```

Rather you can change the variable you used in your loop to get it work.. As then `x` will act as list only like you declared earlier in your method..

Comment: Actually before the offending line he uses x and y in the for loops

Comment: @ajon.. Didn't noticed that.. updated my answer..

Comment: Downvoter can remove the down vote.. As I have updated my post..